# How to prove strong duality by Slater's condition without the assumption $\ker(A^T)=\{0\}$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

In Section 5.3.2 of Boyd, Vandenberghe: Convex Optimization, strong duality is proved under the assumption that ker(A^T)={0} for the linear map describing the equality constraint, though it is remarked that this condition is not necessary. Where can I find a proof of the statement without the assumption on the kernel?

Comment: did you know you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question?

Comment: The assumption is needed (in this version of the proof) in order to prove that there is a non-vertical supporting hyperplane between the sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. While this outcome is at the heart of the strong-duality proof, it can be obtained differently, however it will make the proof much more complicated. Moreover, the assumption that $A$ has the same rank as the equality constraints is very mild

Comment: OK, thanks. It is good to know that the proof of the general case is more complicated. Can you maybe tell me where I can find such a proof? I've had a look at Slater's paper cited at Wikipedia, but already the problem setting seemed quite different there, so it seemed it would take quite a bit of effort to understand it.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a resource, but I'll give it a try myself

Answer (score 2):

I think that the proof in the book can be very easily modified to work for the rank-deficient case, too, by simply using a better version of the supporting hyperplane theorem: Indeed, the proof for that in the book (and in many other places) gives a trivial supporting hyperplane when the interior of the convex set is empty, namely, one with a normal vector orthogonal to the affine subspace generated by the convex set. However, there also exist non-trivial supporting hyperplanes; one simply has to use the supporting hyperplane theorem in a subspace, and then extend the linear functional to the whole space. I think if we use such a non-trivial supporting hyperplane from the beginning in the proof of Slater's theorem, then $\langle\nu,Ax-b\rangle\ge 0$ for all $x$ in the domain of the problem implies that
$\nu$ has to be perpendicular to $\{Ax-b:\,x\in\mathcal{D}\}$, but then, by the preceding arguments, $(\lambda,\nu,\mu)=(0,\nu,0)$ is perpendicular to $\mathcal{A}$, which contradicts our initial choice of a non-trivial supporting hyperplane.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\mathcal{A}$ as in Boyd's (5.37). Then we can think of $\mathcal{A}$ as an epigraph of $\mathcal{G}$ (again from Boyd).
Let $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}\in\text{ri}\,D$ with $f_i(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})<0,\,i=1,\dots,m$ and $A\tilde{\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{b}=\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$. Also denote by $F=(f_1,\dots,f_m)^T$ the vectors of inequality constraints. Since the vector $(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), \tilde{\mathbf{y}}, f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}))\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}$ is on the relative boundary of $\mathcal{A}=\text{epi}(\mathcal{G})$, it follows by the supporting hyperplane theorem that there exists a separating hyperplane between $(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), \tilde{\mathbf{y}}, f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}))$ and $\mathcal{A}$, meaning that there exists a nonzero vector $(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q},-\alpha)\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+^m\times\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}$ for which \begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathbf{p}^TF(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-\mathbf{q}^T\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\alpha f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})\geq\mathbf{p}^TF(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{y}-\alpha t,\quad \forall (F(\mathbf{x}),\mathbf{y},t)\in\mathcal{A}.
\end{equation}
Since $(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), \tilde{\mathbf{y}}, f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}))$ is on the relative boundary of $\mathcal{A}$ it follows that $(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), \tilde{\mathbf{y}}, f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})+1)\in \mathcal{A}$ as well. Hence we can plug $\mathbf{x}=\tilde{\mathbf{x}},\mathbf{y}=\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$ and $t=f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})+1$ to the equation above and get
$$
\mathbf{p}^TF(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-\mathbf{q}^T\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\alpha f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})\geq\mathbf{p}^TF(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})+\mathbf{q}^T\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\alpha (f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})+1),\quad \iff \alpha\geq 0
$$
After showing that $\alpha\geq 0$ we need to prove that $\alpha\neq 0$. Consider $L=\text{aff}(\mathcal{A})$. Since $\mathcal{A}\subseteq L$ and a supporting hyperplane $(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q},-\alpha)$ by definition does not contain $\mathcal{A}$, it does not contain $L$ as well. Now consider the affine combination $\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}=(1-\lambda)\tilde{\mathbf{x}}+\lambda\mathbf{s},\;\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{r}_{\lambda}$ is the corresponding vector for $A\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}$. The points in this line all lie in the affine set $L$ and $\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}\to\tilde{\mathbf{x}}, \mathbf{r}_{\lambda}\to\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$ as $\lambda\to 0$. Since $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}\in\text{ri}\,D$, for small values of $|\lambda|$ the points $\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}$ lie in $D$. Hence we can plug $\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}$ into $(1)$ and get (after some  algebra)
$$\mathbf{p}^T(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-F(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}))+\lambda\mathbf{q}^T(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{r})-\alpha(f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-f_0(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}))\geq 0.\tag{2}$$
Inequality $(2)$ must hold for sufficiently small positive and **negative** values of $\lambda$. Consider the case when $\alpha=0$. Since $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}\in\text{ri}\,D$ then $f_i(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})<0$ and for $\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}\in D\setminus\text{ri}\,D$ we have $f_i(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda})=0$. This implies that
$$
\mathbf{p}^T\overbrace{(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-F(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}))}^{<0}+\lambda\mathbf{q}^T(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{r})\geq 0.\tag{3}
$$
Then either $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{0}$ or $\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{0}$, but never both, since $(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0},0)$ cannot be a supporting hyperplane. If $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{0}$ then $\lambda\mathbf{q}^T(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{r})\geq 0$ cannot hold true for positive and negative (small) values of $\lambda$, unless $\mathbf{q}=0$. If $\mathbf{q}=0$ then again $\mathbf{p}^T(F(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-F(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}))\geq 0$ can hold for only if $\mathbf{p}=0$. However if $\alpha>0$ there is no problem. Take for example the case where $\mathbf{p}=0$. Then the inequality
$$
\lambda\mathbf{q}^T(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{r})-\alpha(f_0(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-f_0(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda}))\geq 0
$$
will hold. This is because if we analyze the *convex* function $f_0(\mathbf{s}_{\lambda})$ we notice it's monotone decreasing in $\lambda<0$ (it increases as $\lambda$ moves away from zero in the negative direction), hence offsetting the flip of sign from $\lambda\mathbf{q}^T(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{r})$.

Overall we have shown that there exists a non-vertical supporting hyperplane to $\mathcal{A}$ at its boundary, and therefore strong duality holds.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your comment; I was not expecting a complete write-up of a proof! :-) There is one thing I don't yet understand, though. Namely, why is the point in the third line on the relative boundary of $\mathcal{A}$? Of course, it is if we assume that $ran(A)$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$, but then I think the version of the supporting hyperplane theorem in Boyd-Vandenberghe won't help; see my answer to the original question above.